# How to Give Title for graphs from Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, matplotlib

Hello Stack overflow fam!!

I am Plotting graph from multiple Python DataFrames using list as shown below

```
c_qc_1_1_1st = c_qc_1_1.iloc[:, 1:4]
c_qc_1_1_2st = c_qc_1_1.iloc[:, 4:7]
c_qc_1_1_3st = c_qc_1_1.iloc[:, 7:10]
c_qc_1_1_4st = c_qc_1_1.iloc[:, 10:13]
```

```
data = {'UL_Position_Fr_center_datum_hole':[76.5, 76.5, 76.5, 
        76.5,76.5,76.5],
        'Position_Fr_center_datum_hole':[76.8, 76.63, 76.41, 76.90 ,76.50, 
         76.90],
        'LL_Position_Fr_center_datum_hole':[76.3, 76.3, 76.3, 
        76.3,76.3,76.3]  }
  
# sample DataFrame.
c_qc_1_1_1st = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['01-06-2021 02:20:04 PM',
                                '01-06-2021 02:20:05 PM',
                                '01-06-2021 02:20:06 PM',
                                '01-06-2021 02:20:07 PM',
                                '01-06-2021 02:20:08 PM',
                                '01-06-2021 02:20:09 PM'])
```

```
c_qc_1_1_list = [c_qc_1_1_1st ,c_qc_1_1_2st, c_qc_1_1_3st, c_qc_1_1_4st]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)

for d, ax in zip(c_qc_1_1_list, axes.ravel()):
    
    d.plot.line(ax=ax,color=['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'],figsize=(25,20), linewidth = 2, marker = 'o', markersize = '8', rot=30)
```

Now I get 4 Graphs from 4 DataFrames

How do I Give **Unique Titles** which has to be picked from each DataFrames **(c_qc_1_1_2st, c_qc_1_1_2st, c_qc_1_1_3st, c_qc_1_1_4st)** and from 2 nd column name to its respective graphs as **Title**

I have attached image of 1 DataFrame and Plotted graphs for reference.

Need you support
[image: 1st Dataframe Image]
[image: Resultant graph]

Comment: can you add the dataframe as dict instead on an image??

Comment: Sure!!, I have added that